# How To Show Inactive Records On the Page

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox, datatable

I am new in ASP.NET MVC and facing an issue in JQuery. Let me explain you my concern. I am showing some records on page and i have three action buttons (Edit,Delete and Active/Inactive). Now I can see Active Records on my page. I want to see Inactive records also and for this i have used checked box. But I am not able to see the Inactive records. Please help me in this. I have pasted my code and screenshot below.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
        <input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="check1" style="text-align:left" onclick="GetRecords()" />  <label>Show Inactive Items</label>
    </div>
</div>

function GetRecords() {
        $.post("/Home/ShowRecords", function (res) {
            if (res) {
                dataTable.ajax.reload();
                $.notify("Update Successfully", {
                    className: "success",
                    globalPosition: 'top - center'
                });
            }
        })
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Plz help me in this.

Comment: Are you sure you're sending the inactive records from your Action method? Could you share us how your JSON response looks like, please?

Comment: Thanks my issue resolve.

Comment: Glad to help! =)